# Using node element inside sprintf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

so I've been trying to get this part of the program to read a specific file which contains names and numbers in this format

> name number

etc. and store them in a struct list

```
void read_data(char *filename, list *mylist) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    char pass[100];
    int  order;
    char line[1000];

    while (fgets(line, 1000, file) != NULL) {
        list_element *element = malloc(sizeof(list_element));
        sscanf(line, "%s %d", pass, &order);
        sprintf(element->password, "%s", pass);
        element->count = order;
        element->next = NULL;
        insert_front(element, mylist);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

`sprintf` keeps crashing the program with segmentation fault. I've tried `snprintf` and I keep having the same issue.
I can't use a buffer since in this specific task I'm not allowed to use `<string.h>` so `strcpy` is not an option

The struct itself is:

```
struct list_element {
    char *password;
    int count;
    list_element* next;
};
```

Valgrind shows:

```
==25999== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25999==    at 0x4ECC374: _IO_str_init_static_internal (strops.c:51)
==25999==    by 0x4EBD6C2: vsprintf (iovsprintf.c:41)
==25999==    by 0x4EA1093: sprintf (sprintf.c:32)
==25999==    by 0x4008E7: read_data 
==25999==    by 0x400B80: main 
==25999==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==25999==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25999==    by 0x400898: read_data 
==25999==    by 0x400B80: main
```

Any tips on where my error is would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `list_element* element = malloc(sizeof(list_element));`, you are allocating space for the list element, but you do not allocate space for the password to which member `password` shall point to. So your `sprintf(element->password,"%s", pass);` will write to memory which you have not allocated.

Either allocate space before `sprintf` (BTW: `strcpy` would do the job as well):

```
element->password = malloc(strlen(pass)+1);
// sprintf(element->password,"%s", pass);
strcpy(element->password,pass);
```

or write ...

```
element->password = strdup(pass);
```

such that enough space for holding the contents of `pass` gets reserved before `pass`'contents get copied into that space.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, my only issue with that is that I'm not allowed to use string.h at all

Comment: After reallocating memory for element->password before using sprintf the program did run, thank you :)